# using an xml template

Tags: c#, xml

i was just wondering what the best way in c# is to use a template for creating a new xml file and insert the relevant data items?

below is the template and i have marked //here where i shall be inserting elements. The inserted elements have to take the form

```
<node label="value" />
```

Is this tricky to do? is it possible to save a template in a programme and create a new version from it?

Thanks

```
<graph>
  <node label="Batch">
    <node label="Searched Batch">
      //here
    </node>
    <node label="Compound Number">
      //here
    </node>
    <node label="Parent Number">
      //here
    </node>
    <node label="Chemist Name">
      //here
    </node>
    <node label="Quantity Available">
      //here
    </node>
    <node label="Molecular Formula">
      //here
    </node>
    <node label="Notebook Number">
      //here
    </node>
    <node label="Analytical Images">
      <node label ="Click to View Analytical Images Data" />
    </node>
    <node label="Who has Registered Batches">
      //here
    </node>
    <node label="Chemical Structure" >
      <node label="Click to view compound image" />
    </node>
  </node>
</graph>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this exactly answers your questions, but the best way to transform xml documents into other xml, text or html documents, is [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/)